# If H, N are normal subgroups of G, then do all the commutators lie in the intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Okay, I know that this is elementary, but, ah, well.

How do I show that if N and H are normal subgroups of a finite group G with coprime orders, then,
$xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in H\cap N$ for all $x \in H, y \in N$?

I figured that, if all $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in H$, then, $HN/H$ is abelian. And further, that $HN/N$ is isomorphic to $N/ H\cap N$.

Thank you.

Edit: Yes, I also know that $H \cap N = (1),$ the point is eventually to use this fact to show that $xy=yx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $N$ is normal in $G$, and $y\in N$, then $xyx^{-1} \in xNx^{-1} = N$, so $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in Ny^{-1} = N$. (That is, if $N$ is normal in $G$, then $[N, G] \subseteq N$.) Apply similar reasoning to $H$. (If you like, $[N, H] \subseteq [N, G] \subseteq N$, but also $[N, H] \subseteq [G, H] \subseteq H$.)

Comment: Crap.  How did I miss that?

Thanks a lot.